# WSSE header , Sencha Touch 2

Tags: authentication, extjs, sencha-touch-2, wsse

I have a backend api which uses `WSSE` authentication.

I can test my api with chrome extension ( Advanced Rest Client )  and [this](http://www.teria.com/~koseki/tools/wssegen/) tool for generating wsse header , but my real client is a sencha touch app.

**My Question :** Is there a built in library in `Sencha Touch` or `Ext.js` that allow me to generate the `wsse` header or I should do it manually ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmmm it seems that there is not such a tool. I did it manually inspiring from this website

http://www.teria.com/~koseki/tools/wssegen/